# NullPointerException while using setText inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I'm getting NullPointerException while using setText() inside OnBindViewHolder() while implementing recyclerview. I've debugged the entire code but not getting the solution. Please Explain why the 'holder.articleName' is thrown as null object?

Adapter Class:

```
public class ArticleListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleItemViewHolder> {
    String[] articles = {
            "article1",
            "article2",
            "article3",
            "article4",
            "article5"
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ArticleItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_article_list, parent, false);
        return new ArticleItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArticleItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.articleName.setText(articles[position]);
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ArticleListActivity.this, "Article Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.length;
    }
}
```

ViewHolder Class:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArticleItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView articleName;
    CardView cardView;

    public ArticleItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.articleName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.articleName);
        this.cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }
}
```

Comment: layout should contains R.id.articleName

Comment: it already contains that.

Comment: it just cannot figured it out the reason for the nullpointerexception thrown

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the layout which has the TextView **articleName** is in the Layout page referenced here **R.layout.activity_article_list** and not any other layout page!